# How to set the height of a div to match the remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page which is divided into 4 sections.

1. Header
2. Menu
3. Content
4. Footer

I am using 1 div for each section and 1 div which wraps all the 4 divs.

My header's height is 50px, the menu's height is 50px, and the footer's height is 20px.

Then I try setting the menu's height to 100%. Menu div is taking the height of its container which is creating scrollbars in my page.

The CSS is as follows:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Is it possible with CSS alone or I have to use JavaScript also?

Comment: Why you use `width:100%;` on block-level elements?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want the header to be the top 50px of the browser window, the menu to be the next 50px, the footer to be the bottom 20px, and the content area all the area between the menu and the footer with no scrollbars?

Comment: You should not use percentage in this case as your menu is the container's child.... Better go with pixel units.

Comment: @vishalkin - Assuming I'm correct in my assumption of what he means, it's perfectly possible, even pre-html5.

Comment: @88ad: i am saying about using a width in percentage..

Comment: If it were me doing it, I'd use javascript.  I can't think of any neat and clean CSS method for mixing percentage and pixel sizes to fill the screen or to use a dynamic pixel size for that extra area.  The only way I can think of for CSS would be to use conditional statements based on the screen resolution to create static sizes for commonly used resolutions, but that would be a lot of extra CSS, wouldn't be dynamic and wouldn't cover all scenarios.

Comment: I am new to designing area. I never knew that block elements occupy the container's width by default. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another **Pure CSS solution**, that works without specifying any height whatsoever.
[this solution deserves its own answer]

Here's a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Mspxt/4/)

### Why is it good?

because maybe your header will change one day affecting his height, or your menu will grow, or your footer will need an extra line causing his height to grow..

all of that changes will cause you to re-fix another height for the changing element, and recalculate the right height for the content.

my solution makes it easier, because all the parts are fluid.
let them take the space they need in the page, and the content will always take the remaining height.

### Browser support:

**Tested On:** IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. *(not working on older IE, not tested on other browsers)*

### any Downsides?

yes. unfortunately, because of the way that this trick works, you will need to change the arrangement of your HTML.

I found a Pure CSS way to create a `div` container, with two child `div`'s.
the first will take the exact height he needs, and the second will take the remaining of the container height's.

but what if I want the opposite scenario,
What if I want second `div` to take his exact space and the first `div` to take the container's remaining height?

I didn't find an easy way to do that with Pure CSS.
thats why, I actually reverse the order of the `div`s, the first holds the second data, and the second holds the first data, now we let the first div to take his exact height, and the second stretch to the end of the container as we want, and then I rotate their view via CSS to make them appear in order.

For your case  it means that you will have to create the HTML in that order.

1. Header
2. Menu
3. Footer
4. Content

### The Solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">I'm in the header</div>
    <div class="Menu">I'm in the menu</div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper Container Inverse">
            <div>
                <div class="Footer">I'm in the footer</div>
            </div>
            <div class="HeightTaker">
                <div class="Wrapper">
                    <div class="Content">
                        I'm in the content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.HeightTaker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .HeightTaker:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Inverse, .Inverse > *
{
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.Header
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.Menu
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #6ea364;
}
.Content
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
.Footer
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #b5a8b7;
}
```

Comment: I will go with this solution because I need not specify heights. I am trying analysing this answer. Why should I use the content property?

Comment: because if you don't specify it in a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element, the element will not be rendered.

Comment: fascinating solution! I noticed only one minor bug.  Could be different on other platforms (I'm on Mac Chrome), but scrolling of the content did not work for me unless I added `z-index:1` to `.HeightTaker`. Personally, I like the calc solution better though.

Comment: The calc() solution is cleaner if you know the heights of all other elements, and they aren't going to change. About the scrolling issue, I noticed this problem is only in Chrome and safari and if you are scrolling with the scrollbar (manually) it works. I will add your fix to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thought.  May not work for your specific problem, but it does address the issue of mixing pixels and percents.  Under the current definition of the problem, you use a fixed height for both the top (header, menu) and bottom (footer).  But you want to have the content take up the rest.  One solution would be to pad the top and bottom of the container with the same height of the header and menu on top and the same height as the footer on the bottom.  The problem then is that you have a 100% height container plus 100px on top and 20px on bottom.  But there's a CSS convention for that.  It's called [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and is very cross browser compatible (as long as you include -moz).  in effect, it calculates 100% height ***after*** including the padding.  Therefore, 100% height plus all the padding still equals 100% height.

In practice it looks like this

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html, body, .container {
    min-height: 100%;
    background:#eee;
}

.header {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.footer {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%; /* needed because this one is position absolute */
    bottom: 0%;
    position:absolute;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; /* needed because this one is position absolute */
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* here's the kicker */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto; /* don't panic. they take the place of normal scroll bars*/
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S

#### Source

http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S/show
http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S/6/show (with -moz for firefox)

### Pros

Obviously, the point is that you can have 100% height elements with padding to compensate for footer and header

### Cons

You have to use position absolute for the content and footer, and you have to apply position relative with z-index to the header area

### EDIT

After a little more experimenting, I found that it's probably best to use height instead of min-height and apply `overflow:auto` or the like.  That way the page has appropriate sidebars if the content gets to be too large: http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S/3/

Comment: If you want to support IE6/7 with box-sizing you'll also need to include a polyfill such as: https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill

Comment: the footer is overlaying the content. I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: @avrahamcool No, the footer does not overlay the content.  It has padding on the bottom to prevent that.  For the /3 example it uses a black border, but if you change it to transparent and make it 30px, you'll see that it does not overlay the content.

Comment: see this [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjhfbuczi1hr7ii/Screenshot%202013-09-28%2020.31.39.png)

Comment: @avrahamcool that's fixed in the [/3 example](http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S/3/) but not for firefox.  As I stated, you need -moz for border-box to work in firefox. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WLR5S/6/

Comment: OK, If you use a property that need vendor specific prefix, you should add them to your working fiddle, and not as a comment in the answer..

Comment: It was in the main description text [all the way back from when I first posted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19069062/revisions#spacer-a96b1854-6eb6-4463-9015-882cbdac2c19)

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Mostly people just don't understand it. Lots of developers will get tripped up on it taking the element out of the document flow and it can be frustrating when you have to make sure your z-indexes are correct. One plausible scenario would be a developer adding an element in the DOM tree immediately after a position absolute element expecting it to show up at the bottom of the absolute element, but it doesn't.  Instead it's usually hidden behind it unless `left`, `top`, `z-index` are used. It also gets abused which can cause bigger headaches. simpler is best whenever possible.

Comment: All that being said, I do think this is an inappropriate use of positioning

Answer (score 2):

### Pure CSS Solution

using `calc()` *(CSS3)*

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NaxRa/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="menu">menu</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    /*min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 500px;*/ /*You can uncomment that back if you want)*/
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 50px;
}
#menu {
    height: 50px;
}
#content {
    height: calc(100% - 120px); /*120 = 50 + 50 + 20*/
    overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
    height: 20px;
}
```

notice I removed your `width:100%` because this is the default behavior of a block element like a div.

This can also be done without stating any height **at all**, with Pure CSS.
Check my second answer in that page.

Comment: This solution is working fine at least on chrome 29.x and firefox 24.0. I never knew that css3 has calc method. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Check out my second answer, the solution can deal with a variable height. + Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. :)